# cmake execute_process TIMEOUT uses

Tags: cmake, timeout

We have `TIMEOUT 3600` used across many `execute_process` calls.
Some of our slow servers often exceed the timeout and builds fail as expected. 
However, this is often causing issues and we keep increasing the timeout intervals.

Now I'm thinking to remove timeout completely.

Is there a reason for using the `TIMEOUT` option other than failing?
Why should we have `TIMEOUT` at all (e.g., none of `add_custom_target` commands has this feature)? Why use it only in `execute_process` (request is not meant for CTest)?

Comment: It is meant to prevent CMake from waiting forever when a process hangs. Often you know a process should be finished within seconds.

Comment: It's difficult to tell without knowing the actual task that is guarded with a timeout. But generally speaking I would remove the individual timeouts. I have a timeout for the complete build process running on a Jenkins server. There it calculates an average over the last builds and you can give a percentage value of how much your build may differ (I use a "Timeout as a percentage of recent non-failing builds" of 400% so only the really hanging tasks will be terminated).

Comment: we are using it across compile, execute, also to generate shell commands, ant commands. example `execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ./ --config ${p_CONFIG} ${trg} ${cln} ${mkFlag}`

Answer (score 0):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

Generally speaking I would remove the individual timeouts.

I have [a timeout for the complete build process running on a Jenkins server](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin). There it calculates an average over the last builds and you can give a percentage value of how much your build may differ (I use a "Timeout as a percentage of recent non-failing builds" of 400% so only the really hanging tasks will be terminated).